# TCL connect to an existing process

Tags: tcl, expect

Let's say that I spawned an SSH session with a TCL script. How do I interact with this session from another TCL script? Is it possible to connect to a process already spawned by another script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use [GNU `screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) inside that ssh session. Then you'll be able to disconnect from it in your expect script, and then reconnect to it from another ssh session (which might be inside your expect script, of course).

The use of `screen` itself is a topic for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/), but from the perspective of `expect`, it's not really much more complicated than automating whatever you had inside the ssh session before; maybe a little bit more work (particularly as you've got to deal with the differences between creating a new screen session and finding+connecting to an existing one) but its not really that much more. Definitely less than trying to emulate the behaviour in other ways!

You do *not* want to try to run the ssh session inside screen (i.e., the reverse of what I recommend). This is because network connections are the things that are most likely to be torn down by outside intervention.

You might run your expect scripts inside a local screen. That's out of scope of what we're talking about here.

Comment: Be aware that both expect and screen use the Unix virtual terminal system quite extensively, and virtual terminals are a strictly limited resource. Don't overuse these facilities or you'll end up having weird problems logging in…